# Using amazon oAuth for alexa skill fails to link the skill. Anything specific to be done for India?

Tags: oauth, alexa-skills-kit, login-with-amazon

The Amazon skill was set up with login with Amazon for oAuth, after successful login into Amazon, the Alexa app throws up and error saying "an error occurred while attempting to link Alexa with . Please try again later" Are there any other configurations that I might be missing? Alexa was launched in India very recently. Anything specific that needs to be done for this region?

[Link to the skill configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CAv1.png)

[Link to LWA configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lmk6n.png)

Comment: paste here the screenshot of the OAuth config with blurred credentials, then only we can say anything.

Comment: Added link to the screenshot of the configuration

Comment: Did you have made an app for the Login in the Apps & Services in Developers console? Refer to this link for more clarity, https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/post/tx3cx1etrzz2npc/alexa-account-linking-5-steps-to-seamlessly-link-your-alexa-skill-with-login-wit

Comment: I followed the same link for the set up . I had set up an LWA login. Thats where the client id and secret came from

Comment: I have done through Implicit Grant and it was working fine. Trying changing the Redirect URLs in the web settings of the App. Do also paste the config of App in the Apps and Services.

Comment: the smart home skill doesn't support implicit grant. Added a link to the LWA config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in the skill configuration. In the current release of the smart home skills API, Amazon provides developers with an inbound endpoint on Alexa. This allows developers to send asynchronous messages to the Alexa service.

This requires region-specific lambda functions and an authorization framework set-up by the developer. 
[documentation on sending events to the Event Gateway is here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smarthome/send-events-to-the-alexa-event-gateway.html).
As far as I could find out, this is not yet enabled in India- only EU and the US

In the screenshot attached to the question, you can barely see this enabled under the "Permissions" section.